# Javascript: Forwarding function calls that take variable number of arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments

I think I need something like ruby's splat `*` here.

```
function foo() {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i];
  }
  return result;
}

function bar() {
  return foo(arguments) // this line doesn't work as I expect
}

bar(1, 2, 3);
```

I want this to return `"123"`, but instead I get `"[object Arguments]"`.  Which makes sense, I suppose.  It's passing the object that represents the arguments, but not the arguments individually.

So how do I simply forward any number of arguments to another function that takes any number of arguments?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since ES6, you can use the [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to call a function, applying the elements of an iterable object as argument values of the function call:

```
function bar() {
  return foo(...arguments);
}
```

Note that you can also *receive* a variable number of arguments as a real array, instead of using the `arguments` object.

For example:

```js
function sum(...args) { //  args is an array
  return args.reduce((total, num) => total + num)
}

function bar(...args) {
  return sum(...args) // this just forwards the call spreading the argument values
}

console.log(bar(1, 2, 3)); // 6
```

In the days of ES3/ES5, to correctly pass the arguments to another function, you needed to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply):

```
function bar() {
  return foo.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

The `apply` method takes two parameters, the first is the `thisObj`, the value of it will be used as the `this` value inside the invoked function, if you use `null` or `undefined`, the `this` value inside the function will refer to the global object, in non-strict mode, otherwise is `undefined`.

The second argument that `apply` expects is an array-like object that contains the argument values to be applied to the function.

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/axafe3/edit).

Answer (score 3):

Try this `return foo.apply(this,arguments)`. Also you can just use `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).join('')` for your foo function.